# SQL query to display number of records based upon column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on query where I need to display n numbers of records based upon column value.

E.g. my input table is as below

```
ITMREF_0    STOFCY_0    ITCSEQ_0    VLTTOT_0
110205        11          7          7.00000
110205        18          1          22.30130
110206        11          5          0.00000
```

Output I want is whatever values is in 3rd column for distinct column value of 1st column.. column value of first column will be repeated that times.

E.g. We have two different numbers for column 1(ITMREF_0) . `110205 and 110206`

For 110205 there are two different values in 3rd columns i.e. 7 and 1 . That means 2nd and 4th columns for 110205 will be repeated from 1 to 7 then for 1

so output should be

```
ITMREF_0    STOFCY_0    ITCSEQ_0    VLTTOT_0
110205        11          1        7.00000
110205        11          2        7.00000
110205        11          3        7.00000
110205        11          4        7.00000
110205        11          5        7.00000
110205        11          6        7.00000
110205        11          7        7.00000
110205        18          1        22.30130
110206        11          1        0.00000
110206        11          2        0.00000
110206        11          3        0.00000
110206        11          4        0.00000
110206        11          5        0.00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with a numbers table or numbers `cte`:

rextester: http://rextester.com/UCEM72371

```
create table t (
    ITMREF_0 int 
  , STOFCY_0 int 
  , ITCSEQ_0 int 
  , VLTTOT_0 decimal(19,6) 
);
insert into t values 
    (110205 ,11 ,7 ,7) 
  , (110205 ,18 ,1 ,22.3013) 
  , (110206 ,11 ,5 ,0) ;
```

numbers cte:

```
  /* numbers table */
with a as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, numbers as (
  select n = row_number() over (order by (select 1))
    from         a as deka
      cross join a as hecto
      cross join a as kilo
      --cross join a as [tenK]
      --cross join a as [hundredk]
      --cross join a as mega
    )
```

query:

```
select 
    t.ITMREF_0
  , t.STOFCY_0
  , ITCSEQ_0 = n
  , VLTTOT_0
from t 
  inner join numbers 
    on numbers.n <= t.ITCSEQ_0
order by 
    t.ITMREF_0
  , t.STOFCY_0
  , n
```

results:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| ITMREF_0 | STOFCY_0 | ITCSEQ_0 | VLTTOT_0  |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|   110205 |       11 |        1 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        2 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        3 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        4 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        5 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        6 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       11 |        7 | 7,000000  |
|   110205 |       18 |        1 | 22,301300 |
|   110206 |       11 |        1 | 0,000000  |
|   110206 |       11 |        2 | 0,000000  |
|   110206 |       11 |        3 | 0,000000  |
|   110206 |       11 |        4 | 0,000000  |
|   110206 |       11 |        5 | 0,000000  |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with        cte as
            (
                select  * 
                from    mytable 

                union all   

                select  ITMREF_0,STOFCY_0,ITCSEQ_0 - 1,VLTTOT_0 
                from    cte 
                where   ITCSEQ_0 > 1
            )
select      * 
from        cte 
order by    ITMREF_0,STOFCY_0,ITCSEQ_0
```

---

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ITMREF_0 | STOFCY_0 | ITCSEQ_0 | VLTTOT_0 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 1        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 2        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 3        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 4        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 5        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 6        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 11       | 7        | 7.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110205   | 18       | 1        | 22.30    |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110206   | 11       | 1        | 0.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110206   | 11       | 2        | 0.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110206   | 11       | 3        | 0.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110206   | 11       | 4        | 0.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 110206   | 11       | 5        | 0.00     |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.ITMREF_0
      ,A.STOFCY_0
      ,ITCSEQ_0 = B.N
      ,A.VLTTOT_0
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Top (A.ITCSEQ_0) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) b
```

Returns

```
ITMREF_0    STOFCY_0    ITCSEQ_0    VLTTOT_0
110205      11          1           7.000000
110205      11          2           7.000000
110205      11          3           7.000000
110205      11          4           7.000000
110205      11          5           7.000000
110205      11          6           7.000000
110205      11          7           7.000000
110205      18          1           22.301300
110206      11          1           0.000000
110206      11          2           0.000000
110206      11          3           0.000000
110206      11          4           0.000000
110206      11          5           0.000000
```